# How to set the virtual machine image details e.g. publisher, offer, sku and version

Tags: azure, gitlab-ci, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure

I have a Terraform script that creates a Virtual Machine on Azure based on this image from the Azure Marketplace:
https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/gitlab.gitlab-ce

But I don't know how to identify the values to put in these fields:

- publisher
- offer
- sku
- version

This is a snippet from the Terraform script

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "gitlab_vm" {
  # ... other configuration

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "GitLab"
    offer     = "GitLab Community Edition"
    # sku       = "???"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  # ... other configuration
}
```

If I run the previous details with `terraform plan` and e.g. `publisher = "GitLabXXX"` (something that does not exist), then Terraform does not raise any error. When I run `terraform apply` after a while an error is raised and the VM resource is not created (although all the other resources e.g. the networking stuff are created).

This applies in a similar way to Azure ARM templates:

```
"imageReference": {
    "publisher": "[variables('pubName')]",
    "offer": "[variables('offerName')]",
    "sku" : "[parameters('skuName')]",
    "version":"latest"
},
```

I have some virtual machine that are up and running with a similar Terraform configuration that I found on the internet (see the Ubuntu example below), but what are the rules to translate the information from the Azure Marketplace webpage to the script?

```
  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way to do this, but I typically use the Azure CLI to get the publisher, offer, SKU, and version.  First, if you do something like:

> az vm image list --offer GitLab -o table --all

You'll get back a list with the offer, publisher, SKU, URN, and Version.  In your case, it should be something like this for gitlab-ce:

- Publisher: gitlab
- Offer: gitlab-ce
- SKU: gitlab-ce
- Version: 1.0.4

I'm pretty sure the azurerm provider just calls ARM with these values so it should match what you get from the CLI, though I can certainly be corrected on this if I'm mistaken.

You'll also need to include a [plan block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine.html#plan).  The details for that can be retrieved via the CLI with something like this:

> az vm image show --location westus --urn gitlab:gitlab-ce:gitlab-ce:1.0.4 -o json

So your plan block would look something like:

```
plan {
  name = "gitlab-ce" 
  publisher = "gitlab"
  product = "gitlab-ce"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Azure Powershell, use:

##### 1. Find `publishername` for region:

```
$locName = "westeurope"
Get-AzVMImagePublisher -Location $locName | Select PublisherName | findstr -i "gitlab"

gitlabinc1586447921813
gitlabinc1659373855767
gitlab
```

##### 2. Find `imageoffer` by Publisher:

```
$publisherName = "<publisher_name>"
Get-AzVMImageOffer -Location $locName  -PublisherName $publisherName
```

##### 3. Find `skuname` for the offer:

```
$offer = "<offer_name>"
Get-AzVMImageSku  -Location $locName -PublisherName $publisherName -Offer $offer
```

##### 4. Find `version` for the SKU:

```
$sku = "<sku_name>"
Get-AzVMImage -Location $locName -PublisherName $publisherName -Offer $offer -Skus $sku
```